# convert .net code to javascript unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, postman

I was wondering whats the equivalent of this .NET code to javascript and prequest script postman:

```
private  string GetRequestTimeStamp()
{
    DateTime epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    DateTimeKind.Utc);
    TimeSpan timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;
    string requestTimeStamp = Convert.ToUInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
    return requestTimeStamp;
}
```

I tried this but it's inconsistent

```
function epochTime()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.getTime();
    var o = t + "";
    return o.substring(0, 10);
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *inconsistent*?

Comment: Are the results of each off from each other by a significant number of seconds?

Comment: I run those two and got the diff but only as I did not run them at the same time so if you get values apart then it means there's must be something off elsewere